# chasing enemy in an endless runner

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics

I've been trying to code this for days now, without success.
My game is a 2D endless runner. My hero is locked onto a specific point on the X-axis. The obstacles are randomly spawned (height and distance) buildings.
I'd like to add a chasing enemy to the game. Currently for visuals only.

```
 chasingCopNode = CopSprite.newInstance(position: CGPoint(x: -90, y: 0))
 let follow = SKAction.moveTo(x: thiefNode.position.x - 50, duration: 5)
 let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2)
 let fallBehind = SKAction.moveTo(x: -90, duration: 4)
 let chasingSequence = SKAction.sequence([follow, wait, fallBehind])
 chasingCopNode.run(chasingSequence)
 chasing = true
 self.addChild(chasingCopNode)
```

I created this to move tha chasing sprite along the X-axis.
In my update function, I simply update the Y position of the enemy with the hero's Y position.

That is working, but not quite the thing I need. Since the Y positions are the same, the enemy sprite is flying sometimes (because there is no building under it).

I couldn't come up with any working ideas for the movement on the Y-axis.
I was thinking maybe add a function that calculates the needed Y impulse for the enemy to land on the next building, but I was not able to do that correctly.

thank you for your help!

Comment: You do not want to follow the Y of the player, you want to follow the Y of the next building.  No impulse is needed, you can simply use SKActions to calculate the speed and movement needed to perform this.

Comment: How can I identify my current and next building? These are added to a scrolling SKNode as children. Also I'm not sure what SKAction you mean exactly.
Thank you!

Comment: When you spawn the node, you know everything about it.  Plan your actions at the time the node spawns

Comment: The chasing enemy is spawned periodically, not at the beginning. If I use the buildings as my Y waypoint, can I achieve a jumping like movement?

Comment: It doesn’t matter when the enemy is spawned.  And yes, your enemy path is predetermined, so you can make him move however you want.

Comment: you mean i should create a path during spawning the building then follow it with the enemy? i’m kinda lost here

Comment: This isnt hard. You are just overthinking it.  When a building spawns, you know its position.  You also know where your enemy will end up being based on the path you provide it (it starts with no path or his spawning point). So you take the end  of your enemy path, and add on to it the movement required to get him to the next building.  How you build this enemy path is on you.

Comment: I managed to create a path with the spawning buildings. I'm adding points from the beginning until the player dies. The path looks good, my only problem is that I don't know how to achieve my enemy following the path from the spawn point of the enemy till the end of its lifetime. Also, I'd like to achieve a movement on the X-axis similar to my original code without any success yet